# Recursive pathfinding algorithm keeps returning None

Tags: python, recursion, path-finding

To find a path in a 2D map, I call `get_building_path()` on a `Person` instance, but it keeps returning `None`. I have no idea what is going wrong as I am pretty new to Python.

Below I have provided code needed to reproduce the issue. I have tried many things but I still don't understand why it keeps returning `None`:

```
from random import randint

width = 1400
height = 700
gridSize = 20
people = []
buildings = []
map = [['' for c in range(int(width/gridSize))] for r in range(int(height/gridSize))]

class Person():
    def __init__(self,row,col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
    def getMin(self,paths): # find shortest path
        if (len(paths) == 0): return [] # if nothing was found, return an empty list
        min = paths[0]
        for n in range(1,len(paths),1):
            if ((paths[n] != None and len(paths[n]) < len(min)) or min==[None]): # make sure [None] is not returned since that would be the shortest
                min = paths[n]
        return min
    def path_helper(self,visited,path,row,col,destR,destC): # destR and destC are the row and col of the target position
        if ((row,col) in visited or map[row][col] != 'road' or row < 0 or row > len(map)-1 or col < 0 or col > len(map[0])-1):
            return None # make sure the current position has not been visited, and is in bounds of the map
        path.append([row,col]) # add current position to the path
        visited.append((row,col)) # mark current position as visited
        if (row == destR and col == destC): # return the path if we found the destination
            return path
        others=[] # look in all four directions from the current position
        others.append(self.path_helper(visited,path[:],row-1,col,destR,destC))
        others.append(self.path_helper(visited,path[:],row+1,col,destR,destC))
        others.append(self.path_helper(visited,path[:],row,col-1,destR,destC))
        others.append(self.path_helper(visited,path[:],row,col+1,destR,destC))
        others.remove(None) # remove any path that did not find anything
        return self.getMin(others)
    def get_path(self,row,col):
        return self.path_helper([],[],self.row,self.col,row,col) #call to recursive helper function
    def get_building_path(self,type):
        all = []
        for b in buildings:
            if (b.type == type):
                all.append(b)
        target = all[randint(0,len(all)-1)] #get a random buildings of type 'type'
        return self.get_path(target.row,target.col)
class Building():
    def __init__(self,type,row,col):
        self.type = type
        self.row = row
        self.col = col

midrow = int(height/gridSize/2) #get midpoint of the map
midcol = int(width/gridSize/2)
people.append(Person(midrow+1,midcol+2))
for n in range(0,3,2): #add new buildings to buildings list, along with the map
    buildings.append(Building('house',midrow+n,midcol-2))
    map[midrow+n][midcol-2] = buildings[len(buildings)-1]
    buildings.append(Building('school',midrow+n,midcol-1))
    map[midrow+n][midcol-1] = buildings[len(buildings)-1]
    buildings.append(Building('workplace',midrow+n,midcol))
    map[midrow+n][midcol] = buildings[len(buildings)-1]
    buildings.append(Building('store',midrow+n,midcol+1))
    map[midrow+n][midcol+1] = buildings[len(buildings)-1]
    buildings.append(Building('restaurant',midrow+n,midcol+2))
    map[midrow+n][midcol+2] = buildings[len(buildings)-1]
for n in range(-2,3,1): #add roads to connect the buildings together
    map[midrow+1][midcol+n] = 'road'

testPath = people[0].get_building_path('house')
print(testPath)
```

If you would like to visually see how the buildings and roads are positioned, here is a picture of it:
[image: graphical representation]

From left to right, the buildings are 'house', 'school', 'workplace', 'store', 'restaurant'.

The blue circle represents the person.

(The top left building has a position of (17,33) (row,col)

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Though I would suggest just following your debugger to see where it turns into `None`.

Comment: Ok I will work on making an MRE, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

- `others.remove(None)` only removes the first occurrence of `None`
- `map[row][col] != 'road'` will be True when arriving at the target, so this test should be only done *after* you have verified that you have not yet arrived at the target.
- `map[row][col] != 'road'` will potentially give an error when `row` or `col` are out of range, so you should *first* do that range check

So `path_helper` should be corrected to:

```
    def path_helper(self,visited,path,row,col,destR,destC):
        path.append([row,col])
        # next IF should come before the other IF:
        if row == destR and col == destC:  # no parentheses needed
            return path
        # reorder conditions in next IF statement
        if (row,col) in visited or row < 0 or row > len(map)-1 or col < 0 or col > len(map[0])-1 or map[row][col] != 'road':
            return None
        visited.append((row,col))
        others=[]
        others.append(self.path_helper(visited,path[:],row-1,col,destR,destC))
        others.append(self.path_helper(visited,path[:],row+1,col,destR,destC))
        others.append(self.path_helper(visited,path[:],row,col-1,destR,destC))
        others.append(self.path_helper(visited,path[:],row,col+1,destR,destC))
        others = list(filter(None, others))  # delete ALL occurrences of None
        return self.getMin(others)
```

There are some other things that could be improved (like using a `set` for `visited`, and not shadowing the native `map` function with your own variable), but the above mentioned changes will make it work.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly!